# Get documents for base class and inheriting classes in one query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, polymorphism, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a `Mongo Collection` of `TaskBase` documents. `TaskBase` has three subclasses. I created a collection manager for this collection (from a generic manager I already use). When I create, update or retrieve a subclass of `TaskBase` I get the correct type and no exception.

I created the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<TaskBase> GetTasksByAppId(string appId)
{
   var entityQuery = Query<TaskBase>.EQ(t => t.AppOId, appId);
   return this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Find(entityQuery).ToList();
}
```

When I run this I get an exception that `Element [some element existing only in a subclass] is not a property or member of TaskBase` I understand why I am getting this exception, I just don't know what to do about it.
I would like to get a collection of ALL the types of tasks that could be associated with an App.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to show the driver your class hierarchy. There are 2 options, the first using `BsonKnownTypes` and `BsonDiscriminator` attributes, the other using `BsonClassMap`.

### Attributes

Decorate your base class with the specific derived classes you want to include (similar to what you would do in `WCF`). To tell the driver it's the root you also need `BsonDiscriminator`:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(ConcreteTask))]
public class TaskBase
{

}
```

### BsonClassMap

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TaskBase>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ConcreteTask>();
```

### Result

As a result, the document's type discriminator (_t) will be an array, and not a single value. In this case:

```
{ _t : ["TaskBase", "ConcreteTask"] }
```

Comment: @EladLachmi sure, anytime.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party and following i3arnon's answer, if you want to show the driver your classes hierarchy with out adding attributes to your classes , you can follow the BsonClassMap option in such a way

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TaskBase>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
        });

        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ConcreteTask>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
        });
```

and get the same result:
{ _t : ["TaskBase", "ConcreteTask"] }